# Simple Injector IsRegistered method?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I'm trying to integrate Simple Injector into our application and I need to find a way to implement an IsRegistered method to see if a type is registered in the container. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this with Simple Injector is by calling the `GetRegistration` method:

```cs
bool isRegistered = container.GetRegistration(serviceType) != null;
```

This can be simplified using by adding the following extension method in your code base:

```cs
public static bool IsRegistered(this Container container, Type serviceType)
{
    return container.GetRegistration(serviceType) != null;
}
```

We decided to not include such `IsRegistered` method in Simple Injector, because we feel that under normal conditions you shouldn't need it.

Instead of having to query for the existence of a type, a usually better to make sure there is always an implementation registered, even if there's nothing to implement. register an empty implementation (an implementation of the [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern), not to confuse with a [null reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edakx9da.aspx)). Injecting a Null Object makes the consuming code easier, and makes testing easier, because the dependency is simply required and you will lose null checks and calls to `IsRegistered`.